# Jquery post callback function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm having trouble getting my callback function to work in post:

I've got this in a click function. I've tried both `$().click(function(e){..}` and `$().livequery('click', function(e) {`.

```
e.preventDefault();
$.post("test.php", {}, function(data) {
    alert("bang"); //doesn't register
});
alert("bom"); //works fine
```

test.php:

```
echo "bah";
```

Firebug says the return value is "bah" and the request was processed okay.

I've searched through stackoverflow for similar questions but they weren't of any help, google and docs.jquery.com without getting any wiser.

At first I was trying to edit content on the fly inside `$().click` using: `$("#commentbody:first").find(".commentboxnew").prev().`

But now even the alert won't work.

**Edit:**
I fixed it. I had sent a an xml header from my php file (I'm actually using a framework which divides stuff in a lot of php files which made my question kinda bad - sorry about that) and then the outputted text was ill-formatted.

Thanks for the quick response though :)

Comment: Is anything odd showing up in the console tab of Firebug?

Comment: Not that I can see. I just get "POST url 200 OK 595ms". How do you see if it's successful or not?

Comment: If you get a response and the row doesn't appear in red, I guess Firebug feels it's okay.

Comment: I'm not sure you need the empty {}, have you tried without them?

Comment: Yeah, both with and without and I've tried to send different settings too which it accepts.

Comment: thanks.  I had this problem too.  turns out I was returning application/xml content type when I should not have been.  The only data returned was the text "1" or "2".  Firebug showed an Xml error.

Comment: I had the sme issue, except with JSON. Basically, my jquery post request headers (json) was different from my web servers answer (text/html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Firebug or TamperData to make sure that the HTTP request is completing successfully. If it is (and I guess you wrote that it is), then make sure that the request is in fact happening because of that Ajax call (and not from the browser simply submitting a form, for example).